# web.config redirect works rewrite fails with resource not found

Tags: iis, web-config

I want to rewrite a request to a specific path to another domain:

```
<rule name="Redirect Lookup to new api" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="api/lookup" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/lookup" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```

It works with redirect, but with rewrite I get this error:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: Mistake 3, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: I don't think Rewrite will work with another domain. I believe it only transforms resource path inside the same server. If you need to hide from the visitor the fact the resource is located somewhere else, you need try to setup something like a reverse proxy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).